# Why am I getting a recursive error when I generate dataframe with an argument from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, syntax, arguments

I generate dataframe get_your_holdings, and use dataframe.apply to send each row to get_fund_holdings.
I'm not even sure this is right way to do that, but before I address that I noticed in my test file here I get a recursive error just from trying to generate a dataframe--see below.

```
import pandas as pd


def get_your_holdings():
    your_holdings = [['foo', 100], ['bar', 200]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(your_holdings, columns=['Symbol', 'Equity'])
    return df


def get_fund_holdings(symbol, equity):

    # IRL, foo and bar are scraped, instead of being kept as lists in the code...
    foo = [['aapl', 0.6], ['amzn', 0.3], ['msft', 0.2]]
    bar = [['tsla', 0.4], ['amzn', 0.5], ['goog', 0.2]]

    df = pd.DataFrame(symbol, columns=['Symbol', '% Holding'])
    total_equity = equity * 100
    df['% Holding'] = total_equity * df['% Holding']

    df.rename(columns={'% Holding': 'Equity'}, inplace=True)

    return df


def main():
    df = get_your_holdings()

    # certainly not sure if this is right.
    # was originally going to ask about this
    # but want to make sure get_fund_holding works
    results = (df.apply(lambda x: get_fund_holdings(x['Symbol'], x['Equity']), axis=1, result_type='expand'))
    breakpoint()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Not sure if the full traceback is useful because its quite long. Highlights include:

```
  File "C:/Users/jajam/PycharmProjects/heatmap/test.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    results = (df.apply(lambda x: get_fund_holdings(x['Symbol'], x['Equity']), axis=1, result_type='expand'))
  File "C:/Users/jajam/PycharmProjects/heatmap/test.py", line 16, in get_fund_holdings
    df = pd.DataFrame(symbol, columns=['Symbol', '% Holding'])
  File "C:\Users\jajam\anaconda3\envs\finance\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 590, in __init__
    raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

and

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Unexpected error, recovered safely.
```

Is there a way I should be calling this? I'm also not sure how to parse the data I get returned from the lamda x, but I was going to make a separate question when the syntax here is actually right.

Comment: What output are you trying to get in the end?

Comment: I want to use each row in get_your_holdings as arguments for get_fund_holdings, and eventually recieve a dictionary or dataframe containing key: symbol and value: equity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do at least the minimal tracing of your program:

```
def get_fund_holdings(symbol, equity):
    print("ENTER get_fund_holdings", symbol, equity)
    
    # IRL, foo and bar are scraped, instead of being kept as lists in the code...
    foo = [['aapl', 0.6], ['amzn', 0.3], ['msft', 0.2]]
    bar = [['tsla', 0.4], ['amzn', 0.5], ['goog', 0.2]]

    df = pd.DataFrame(symbol, columns=['Symbol', '% Holding'])
```

This gives the output

```
ENTER get_fund_holdings foo 100
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
```

This makes the problem obvious: the DataFrame constructor requires the first argument to be `data`, the contents to be put into the data frame, in some recognized 2D format.  All you gave it was a string, `"foo"`.  This is what made the construction fail.

You seem to expect that your string `"foo"` will be magically understood as a reference to the variable `foo`.  Variables don't work that way: the data value and the variable name as distinct entities.

Instead, you must *explicitly* set up that correspondence; I've added more tracing to show you the functionality:

```
def get_fund_holdings(symbol, equity):
    print("ENTER get_fund_holdings", symbol, equity)
    
    # IRL, foo and bar are scraped, instead of being kept as lists in the code...
    ticker = {
        "foo": [['aapl', 0.6], ['amzn', 0.3], ['msft', 0.2]],
        "bar": [['tsla', 0.4], ['amzn', 0.5], ['goog', 0.2]]
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(ticker[symbol], columns=['Symbol', '% Holding'])
    print("TRACE\n", df)
    total_equity = equity * 100
    df['% Holding'] = total_equity * df['% Holding']

    df.rename(columns={'% Holding': 'Equity'}, inplace=True)
    print("GFH TRACE\n", df)

    return df
```

Output:

```
ENTER get_fund_holdings foo 100
TRACE
   Symbol  % Holding
0   aapl        0.6
1   amzn        0.3
2   msft        0.2
GFH TRACE
   Symbol  Equity
0   aapl  6000.0
1   amzn  3000.0
2   msft  2000.0
ENTER get_fund_holdings bar 200
TRACE
   Symbol  % Holding
0   tsla        0.4
1   amzn        0.5
2   goog        0.2
GFH TRACE
   Symbol   Equity
0   tsla   8000.0
1   amzn  10000.0
2   goog   4000.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
```

Here, you get a new error, based on a subsequent structural problem.  That will be for you to figure out, or a separate Stack Overflow post.